# How to update a javascript object keys value using the index of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of object like

```
const test = [{id: 1, text: "Test"}, { id: 2 , text: "Test 2" } ]
const index =  test.findIndex((listItem) => listItem === test[0])
```

Here I am trying to update the value of `text key` using the index.

I have a solution like this:

```
 const editItemText = (value) => {
    const newList = replaceItemAtIndex(todoList, index, {
      ...item,
      text: value,
    });

    setTodoList(newList);
  };
  
const replaceItemAtIndex =  [...arr.slice(0, index), newValue, ...arr.slice(index + 1)];
```

is there any other option to do so ? Also How does the given solution works ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you update the code and add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: First you have to find the index and then use
```let index = 1; // This is the index value.
test[index]['text']='New text value';```